# Beamer: Emphasize a part of a slide

Tags: beamer, environments, color, emphasis

I am using Beamer to create presentations. I know that it is possible to use environments like Theorem, Definition and so on:

```
\begin{Teorem}
Great theorem
\end{Theorem}
```

It appears in the box of different color with its header "Theorem".

I would like to create the same emphasized box, but without any header. How one can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually depends on the style used, but you can also use the `block`, `alertblock` and `exampleblock` environments to get blocked off text.

Answer (score 0):

The [Beamer User Guide (PDF)](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) has some explanations beginning on page 111. Usually you can just write:

```
\begin{theorem}
   a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: You can also use "Theorem" with a capital "T", as I just found out to my surprise.